Magento + Guzzlehttp - tracking with legacy API endpoint for Klaviyo
Klaviyo is updating their APIs, so we upgraded the extension in Magento to the latest version, but Klaviyo is still seeing an active legacy API on their end. As per their team, "It's the '/track' endpoint and it's on a public API key. The user agent for this API endpoint is called "guzzlehttp"."
I am not familiar with this module and would appreciate input from anyone who has  a better understanding of its integration with Klaviyo and whether there are steps that can be taken to update its API.
Our Magento is on version 2.4.6-p4 with Klaviyo version 4.1.2.
